# Wordpress Customize blog_query

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a snippet of php to echo out all the posts in a few categories.

```
$blog_query = 'showposts=100&cat=8&paged='.$paged;
$posts = query_posts($blog_query);
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
endwhile;
```

It echos out the posts with title and post content.

I want to edit the function so that I can echo the contents out in my own custom format(without post content).

```
<ul id="customList">
<li><a href="[POST LINK]">[POST TITLE]</a></li>
<ul/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul id = "customList">
<?php
$blog_query = 'showposts=100&cat=8&paged='.$paged;
// The Query
query_posts( $blog_query );
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
```

***I tested above code***

OUTPUT will be in format of:

```
<ul id="customList">
<li><a href="[POST LINK]">[POST TITLE]</a></li>
<ul/>
```

Comment: I try using that code and it returns: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14520321 bytes)